# modifying dynamically a ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType by calling AddSubType throws an exception

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I am trying to use ProtoBuf-Net to create a type-agnostic serializer which serializes instances of previously unknwon types.
For this, I am using a ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel, adding dynamically the types of the objects provided to my generic serializer. 
When adding a type, I add the full type hierarchy recursively using reflection: I add the types by calling myTypeModel.Add(type, true) and myBaseTypeMetaType.AddSubType(subTypeIndex, type)

This works fine except if I already used the serializer to serialize a type and then try to add a subtype to this type. Then, I got an InvalidOperationException: "The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated for Serialization.Test.Address"

I tried to set the auto-compile property of the model to false, but this does not solve my issue.

My understanding of the problem is that by default, protobuf-net creates a serializer for a type whenever it has to serialize the type, and once this is done, the ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType can not be modified.
Is this correct?

Do I do something wrong?

Is there other way to achieve my goals?

Thank you for your help.

Louis

Answer (score 0):

It really wants to know the types in advance - otherwise how could it know that it could deserialize, for example. Additionally, note that with your Index usage it is important that you can reliably generate the same key/Type mapping when you want to deserialize the same data.

One simple option, that would work currently, would be to create a whoe new TypeModel, with the old data plus the new; this is not very convenient, granted. I *could* probably support a global reset of a model's serializers, but it would (by necessity) have to release the whole model.

The third and easiest option is of course: know the types in advance. After all - if you don't have a known/fixed definition, it may not be possible to reproduce your data later.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I already picked the simple solution to recreate a new model. In my use case, I expect to have a limited number of unknown types, so, once the system is in steady state, I would not need to recreate the model anymore. 
Also, I want ot use proto-buf to serialize data exchange between 2 entities. So, if they share the same *discovered* types and if I add the type in a consistent way, I should be fine.

Comment: @user1167325 yes; if you can add them in a consistent way it should be fine